# Having issues using Select Case/Case Else logic to produce certain outcomes

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to achieve in my Windows form is to make my button compute a label output depending on calculated variables, but if the variable given in the textbox doesn't match what is listed in the code, a message box appears showing an error, and the label has a different output because of the failed match.

Here's some code to help further explain what I'm working with, and a description of the errors I'm receiving.

I have code that makes a variable, which finds the textbox that has numbers to substring the input and find the output:

```
Dim var1 As String
Dim Sb As String
Sb = Textbox1.Text
var1 = Sb.Substring(0, 3)
```

Then I'm placing that result to a label and trying to use it again to create the next label OR to show the messagebox saying there was an error using this code:

```
Select Case var1
  Case var1 = "(result1)" Or "(result2)" Or "(result3)"
    Dim var2 As String
    var2 = "(Value)"
    varlabel.Text = var2.ToString
  Case Else
    Messagebox.Show("Error occured, input not found.")
End Select
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I run the button's code, the first label will compute and publish successfully, but the second label will not publish correctly and will still show the message box even though I am giving it the correct input for the code to run. Can anyone shed light as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you want it to do:

```
Case var1 = "(result1)" Or "(result2)" Or "(result3)"
```

I can only assume that you haven't bothered to read the documentation for `Select Case` to even try that.  It should be:

```
Case "(result1)", "(result2)", "(result3)"
```

ALWAYS read the documentation first if you have an issue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cy37t14y(v=VS.140,d=hv.2).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help, this worked successfully! I only had that mixed up since I was frantically doing research on If/Then/Else versus Case/Case Else methods, I appreciate the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: That still wouldn't have worked for an `If` statement either.  That code would try to convert each `String` to a `Boolean`, OR the three `Boolean` values and then compare the variable to that.  An `If` should be `If var1 = "(result1)" OrElse var1 = "(result2)" OrElse var1 = "(result3)" Then`.